# Function to sort an array alphabetically with uppercase letters first

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to sort an array alphabetically with uppercase letters first in the array

Example:

```
array(7) {
  ["H"]=>
  int(1)
  ["W"]=>
  int(1)
  ["e"]=>
  int(1)
  ["l"]=>
  int(3)
  ["o"]=>
  int(2)
  ["r"]=>
  int(1)
  ["d"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

My code doesn't sort with uppercase letters, only alphabetically

Here is my code:

```
function count_char($str) {
    $chars = str_split($str);
    $char_counter = Array();
    foreach($chars as $char) 
        if ((ord($char) >= 65 && ord($char) <= 90) || 
            (ord($char) >= 97 && ord($char) <= 122)) {
            if(!isset($char_counter[$char])) $char_counter[$char] = 1;
            else $char_counter[$char] += 1;
        }
    return $char_counter;
}

var_dump(count_char("Hello World"));
```

My desired output is $str, I would like alphabetizing the uppers, then alphabetizing the lowers

Comment: Please include your desired output.  Are we only sorting uppers from lowers?  Or alphabetizing the uppers, then alphabetizing the lowers?

Comment: @mickmackusa edited it sorry

Comment: Would [array_multi_sort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) help? "_Both SORT_STRING and SORT_REGULAR are case sensitive, strings starting with a capital letter will come before strings starting with a lowercase letter._"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scnadir sort order asc put uppercase letters first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173295/scnadir-sort-order-asc-put-uppercase-letters-first)

Comment: Do you want to sort by count or by the key, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ksort()` will do.  You should only call `ord()` once and just store the result to minimize function calls.  ...or better just call `ctype_alpha()` to ensure you are only storing letters.  I recommend adding curly brackets for improved readability.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Vjv9X))

```
function count_char($str) {
    $chars = str_split($str);
    $char_counter = array();
    foreach($chars as $char) {
        if (ctype_alpha($char)) {
            if (!isset($char_counter[$char])) {
                $char_counter[$char] = 1;
            } else {
                ++$char_counter[$char];
            }
        }
    }
    ksort($char_counter);
    return $char_counter;
}

var_dump(count_char("Hello World"));
```

Output:

```
array(7) {
  ["H"]=>
  int(1)
  ["W"]=>
  int(1)
  ["d"]=>
  int(1)
  ["e"]=>
  int(1)
  ["l"]=>
  int(3)
  ["o"]=>
  int(2)
  ["r"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

---

You *could* also condense things like this if you aren't scared off by regex:

```
function count_char($str) {
    $letters = preg_split('~[^a-z]*~i', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if (!$letters) return [];
    $counts = array_count_values($letters);
    ksort($counters);
    return $counters;
}

var_dump(count_char("Hello World"));
```

Comment: Notice the `d` is not where the OP expects it, thats why I removed my answer.

Comment: Where is it supposed to be?  (I'm singing the song and everything)

Comment: at the bottom.. so its sorted by count and then by key.. dunno :s

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would do it like:

```
<?php
$str = "Hello World";

// split the string (ignoring spaces)
$array = str_split(str_replace(' ', '', $str), 1);

// count the chars
$array = array_count_values($array);

// sort naturally
array_multisort(array_keys($array), SORT_NATURAL, $array);

print_r($array);
```

https://3v4l.org/aZqRb

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [H] => 1
    [W] => 1
    [d] => 1
    [e] => 1
    [l] => 3
    [o] => 2
    [r] => 1
)
```

**Edit:** If you want to sort by value and then by key:

```
<?php
$str = "Hello World";

// split the string (ignoring spaces)
$array = str_split(str_replace(' ', '', $str), 1);

// count the chars
$array = array_count_values($array);

// get the keys
$keys = array_keys($array);

// sort my keys
array_multisort($array, $keys);

// combine sorted keys with array
$array = array_combine($keys, $array);

print_r($array);
```

https://3v4l.org/pfEin

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [H] => 1
    [W] => 1
    [d] => 1
    [e] => 1
    [r] => 1
    [o] => 2
    [l] => 3
)
```